# How to log custom application logs generated by Java/Spring Boot app in Azure Application Logs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have a Spring Boot application that uses log4j2 to create a log file into "D:/home/LogFiles/azurefileapp/" folder in Azure Web App. The application can write logs to this folder properly without any issues.

Now the issue I have is I want to share these logs with other developers who are not having access to the Azure Portal. I thought of providing them with below cmd that downloads these logs (using Service Principal).

az webapp log download --resource-group   --name

With above cmd the logs get downloaded but the current log file to which the app is writing the logs won't get downloaded as it is currently under write lock and locked by a process.

I already tried switching from log4j2 to slf4j. But same happens. The latest log file will not get downloaded. Once I stop the web app, I can download the latest log file without any issues.

Is there any way by which any of the following can be done?
1. The latest log file too can be downloaded without stopping the web app using the same "az webapp log download" cmd?
2. Or else, is there a way by which I can directly write to the log files that Azure Web App generates by itself when we switch on Application Logging.
3. Is there a way I can write my custom logs to the Azure Storage Blob through Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of requirements, we have the following options.

- Splunk with Spring Boot
- ELK stack with Spring Boot
- Zipkin with Spring Boot
- Logstash with Spring Boot

There may be many more. In case of Pivotal Cloud Foundary, there is an option to use Loggregator, if there is similar in Azure, you can leverage.